A question on honorifics
السلام عليكم وعلى بيتكم
Can we say "Alahis salam" or “salam Allah aliha” after the blessed names of the compainions of the Holy Prophet(صَلَّى ٱللَّٰهُ عَلَيْهِ وَآلِهِ) and his ahul bayt? (Also, I’m kinda asking the Maliki school’s view on this kinda)
